# Extending storage to new Drive

Tags: mount, storage

I am using Docker to run a content management system (Alfresco).  My 100 Gb root drive is filling up and I have added a new 100 Gb drive to the Ubuntu 18.04 server.  How do I mount the drive so that the data would use the new 100 Gb space?